# How can I add <map> header file in Android NDK using Android Studio 3.x?

Tags: android, c++, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

How can I add  header file in Android NDK using Android Studio 3.x?
It seems 'stl' option is required in a build file. I use Android Studio and cmake.

When I created a map variable, it does not find iterator functions.

vector and pair are okay. Only about map for now.

```
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, int> m;
  m.begin(); # error at compile it says "No matching function"
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can explain how this is C please readd the tag and accept my apology.

Comment: Looks like `map` is missed after `std::`. Also, provide the **exact error message**, please.

Comment: I added a comment. Compiler says "No matching function"

Comment: You DO have a `#include <map>` statement in your C++ code, right?

Comment: @RemyLebeau sure.

Comment: vector, pair are okay. only for map

Comment: Unable to reproduce. What does `app/build.gradle` and `CMakeLists.txt` look like?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DanAlbert This is all about the issue. I found a solution. I think it is a bug on Android Studio 3.x on Mac. Editor says "no matching function" but I compile it. It links all iterator functions with std::map.